# list in form - advice

Tags: javascript, html, forms, selectlist

i have to make a form with many options to choose, in the case, a list of jobs (probably more than 20 jobs in the list)

my question is in your experience how is more convenient way to do this?

with a (I think this have problems in small resolutions if the list is big )

```
<select>
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
//and more
    </select>
```

or  radio buttons with a scrollbar? or if you know a more indicated way to do this, please suggest.

my principal preoccupation is the more intuitive and compatible way to do a list of options (big list) in a form.

thanks. opinions based in you experience and suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the most intuitive way is the autocomplete combobox which you can see here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: my comment to David is a pure coincidence. At same time. I like what you suggest

Comment: Comboboxes are only good if you want a freeform entry with some help for likely options. They are completely the wrong choice for picking one of a set of predefined options.

Answer (score 0):

You should use css to put them in vertical columns so that splits the area up.

Answer (score 0):

A select element is fine for this, 20 options is not a lot. Make sure you sort the options (by label) alphabetically so that people can find the one they are looking for easily (and press a key to skip to that section of the list).

Comment: an idea occur me. and a input that suggests the options available? like the system that google use in your imput. how do you think about that?

Comment: The trouble with suggestions is that they are *suggestions*. It is a nice UI if you want to let the user enter anything they like but help them enter common options. It is dreadful if you want to make the user choose from a list.